# Masking bits in a file in linux - bitwise operations

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, merge

I wanted to mask the bits in a file in linux as follows:

```
 actual : 00-00000000-00000011-00110010-10000000
 expect : 00-00000000-00000001-01101010-00000000
 error  : 00-00000000-00000010-01011000-00000000
```

In the output, the `actual` part should be as it is unless, the `error` is `1` then `actual` bits should be masked with `X`

As it is seen, `error` is **XOR** of `actual` and `expected` data.

Output should look somewhat like this:

```
output : 00-00000000-000000X1-0X1XX010-10000000
```

Is there anyway of doing this using SED,AWK,etc commands?

**What is done so far:**

```
grep 'err' gpbat | sed 's?-??g' | cut -c 11-35 | sed 's?1?X?g' > a1
grep 'act' gpbat | sed 's?-??g' | cut -c 11- > a2
```

But from here, not getting how to merge `a1` & `a2`

Comment: how many of these do you need to process? 1 set? 100 sets? 10,000 sets? 10,000,000 sets?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338890/convert-signed-10-bit-binary-numbers-to-decimal for how to parse binary in bash.

Comment: Then you can use the bitwise `&` operator.

Comment: @jhnc would be obliged if you ,could help me out in doing it JUST for 1 set, thank you sister.

Comment: @Barmar , thank you for the link, however I referred to it for 1 & 0 is fine, but here I wanted to have 'X' in the output.

Comment: You can do that with `sed` or `tr` after you do the bitwise operation.

Comment: @Barmar how do you distinguish `1` from `1` in your `tr` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With many versions of awk:

```
awk '
    /actual/ { split($3,a,"") }
    /error/ { split($3,e,"") }

    END {
        for (i in a)
            c[i] = e[i]==1 ? "X" : a[i]

        for (i = length(c); i>0; --i)
            s = c[i] s

        printf "output : %s\n", s
    }
' gpbat
```

POSIX states that the result of `split` on empty string is undefined behaviour ["to allow a proposed future extension that would split up a string into an array of individual characters"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_18) but I have personally not encountered a version that doesn't already do so. YMMV. For complete portability @markp-fuso's approach using `substr` would be preferred.

---

Or slightly more efficiently (per @markp-fuso):

```
awk '
    /actual/ { n = split($3,a,"") }
    /error/ { split($3,e,"") }

    END {
        for (i = 1; i<=n; ++i)
            o = (o) ( e[i]==1 ? "X" : a[i] )
        print "output :", o
    }
' gpbat
```

And, if the order of input is guaranteed, processing can stop after the "error" line is read, and so the  the `END` actions can move into the `/error/` actions along with an `exit` to avoid having to read the rest of the file:

```
awk '
    /actual/ { n = split($3,a,"") }
    /error/ {
        split($3,e,"")
        for (i = 1; i<=n; ++i)
            o = (o) ( e[i]==1 ? "X" : a[i] )
        print "output :", o
        exit
    }
' gpbat
```

Answer (score 4):

One `awk` idea using the `substr()` function to step through the positions in the strings:

```
awk '
/^actual / { actual = $3 }
/^error /  { error  = $3
             for (i=1;i<=length(error);i++)
                 output = output (substr(error,i,1) == "1" ? "X" : substr(actual,i,1))
             print "output :",output
           }
' gpbat
```

This generates:

```
output : 00-00000000-000000X1-0X1XX010-10000000
```

---

One verbose `GNU awk` (for `patsplit()` support) idea:

```
awk '
/actual[ ]+:/ {   patsplit($3,actual,"[0-9]") }       # split digits from 3rd field and place in array actual[]
/error[ ]+:/  { n=patsplit($3,error ,"[0-9]")         # split digits from 3rd field and place in array error[]
                for (i=1;i<=n;i++)                    # loop through indices of
                    if (error[i]=="1")                # error[] array and if value == "1" then ...
                       actual[i]="X"                  # overwrite corresponding entry in actual[] array with "X"
                for (i=2;i<n;i+=8)                    # for the 2nd, 10th, 18th and 26th entries of actual[] array ...
                    actual[i]=actual[i] "-"           # append a "-"
                printf "output : "                    # start printing output
                for (i=1;i<=n;i++)                    # loop through indices of actual[] array and ...
                    printf "%s", actual[i]            # print to stdout
                print ""                              # terminate the line
              }
' gpbat
```

This generates:

```
output : 00-00000000-000000X1-0X1XX010-10000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. Diligent and brilliant approach.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr).

```
$ txr xbit.tl < data
 output : 00-00000000-000000X1-0X1XX010-10000000
```

```
(flow (get-string)
  (match ` actual : @actual\n\
         \ expect : @nil\n\
         \ error  : @error\n`
          @1
    (mapcar (do if (eql @2 #\1) #\X @1) actual error))
  ` output : @1`
  put-line)
```

Answer (score 1):

might as well directly "add" the bit-strings like they're integers :

```
echo ' actual : 00-00000000-00000011-00110010-10000000
       expect : 00-00000000-00000001-01101010-00000000' |
```

---

```
mawk '{ ___[NR] = $NF } END { NF = +(\
                              FS = OFS = "-" (____ = ""))
                                                __ = 6
    for(_ in ___)____ = (____)___[_] FS

    $(_ = NF) = ____
            _ = __-- 
    while(--_) 
        $_ = sprintf("%.*d", 2^3^(1 < _), $(_+__) + $_)

    gsub(_ = "1","X")
    gsub(_ + _, _)

    print $!(NF = __) }'
```

---

```
00-00000000-000000X1-0X1XX010-X0000000
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/actual/{s//output/;h}
        /error/!d
        G
        :a;s/^1(.*)\n./\1X\n/;s/^[^1](.*)\n(.)/\1\2\n/;s/\n$//;ta' file
```

If a line contains `actual` replace that string by `output` and make a copy.

If a line does not contains `error`, delete it.

Otherwise, append the copy to the current line.

Create a loop.

If the first character is a `1`,replace the character in the same position in the copied line with an `X`, delete the first character and shift the newline one character to the right.

If the first character is not a `1`, delete the first character and shift the newline right by one character.

If the last character of the line is a newline, remove it.

If a substitution has taken place, repeat the loop, otherwise print the result.

N.B. This assumes the `actual` and `error` lines are the same length and follow the same template.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a ruby:

```
ruby -e '
inf=$<.read.split(/\R/).map(&:strip).map{|s| s.split(/\s+:\s+/,2)}.to_h
puts "output : " + inf["actual"].split("").zip(inf["error"].split("")).
    map{|a,e| if e=="1" then "X" else a end}.join("")
' gpbat
```

Prints:

```
output : 00-00000000-000000X1-0X1XX010-10000000
```

The first line creates a hash of the input (assuming a file as posted):

```
echo ' actual : 00-00000000-00000011-00110010-10000000
 expect : 00-00000000-00000001-01101010-00000000
 error  : 00-00000000-00000010-01011000-00000000' >gpbat 

ruby -e '
p $<.read.split(/\R/).map(&:strip).map{|s| s.split(/\s+:\s+/,2)}.to_h' gpbat

{"actual"=>"00-00000000-00000011-00110010-10000000", "expect"=>"00-00000000-00000001-01101010-00000000", "error"=>"00-00000000-00000010-01011000-00000000"}
```

The RH of the second line created the output array as decribed by `zip`ing the strings from `"actual"` and `"error"` together:

```
ruby -e '
inf=$<.read.split(/\R/).map(&:strip).map{|s| s.split(/\s+:\s+/,2)}.to_h
p inf["actual"].split("").zip(inf["error"].split("")).
    map{|a,e| if e=="1" then "X" else a end}
' gpbat

["0", "0", "-", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "-", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "X", "1", "-", "0", "X", "1", "X", "X", "0", "1", "0", "-", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
```

Then join that array into a string and add the other parts for the output.

Answer (score 0):

Perl, just because I love this gibberish:

```
perl -ne 'print; s/actual/output/ and $o=$_;
@E=$_=~/[01]/g if /error/; 
END {$o =~ s/[01]/$E[$i++]==1?X:$&/ge; print $o}' file
```

- for every line of input:

  - print the line
  - substitute actual with output (`s/actual/output/`) and if that succeeds:

    - save the line (`$_`) as `$o`
  - if the line matches `/error/`, save the `[01]` bits as array `@E` using match `/[01]/g`
- At the `END {}` of the input:

  - substitute every bit in string `$o` with the result of this expression:

    - `$E[$i++]==1?X:$&` : if the corresponding bit in array `@E` is 1, then replace with X.  Otherwise, replace with the match `$&` (no change)
  - print string `$o`

> *Note that generating the "error" from just the two actual&expect lines is also fun perl using similar `s///ge` iteration:*

```
perl -ne 'print; @A=$_=~/[01]/g if /actual/; 
s/expect/error / and s/[01]/(0+$&)^$A[$i++]/ge and print' file
```

> ... There the bitwise XOR operator `^` can be used, but I found that it required the `0+` numification of the match `$&`.